# How does Random Forest calculate Out-of-Bag error in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

1. Does scikit-learn compute oob error based on accuracy for each tree, then average them up?
2. Or does scikit-learn perform some lookups first, and compute the ***real*** generalization error as mentioned in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68740/computing-out-of-bag-error-in-random-forest?rq=1) post?
3. If `oob_score` (as in `RandomForestClassifier` and `BaggingClassifier`) is turned on, does random forest still use soft voting (default option) to form prediction rules? I'm asking this because if the prediction is built upon soft voting, but oob error is based on hard voting (not probability-based), then it's inconsistent imho.

Comment: Assuming these are undocumented, the fastest way to find out your own answer is to view the sklearn source and/or train up a quick example RF and inspect its results and scores.

Comment: @smci Yea, I would take a look when I have time. But please feel free to answer/comment on the question if you know the answer!

Comment: Based on Andreas Mueller's (core sklearn developer) [explanation](https://youtu.be/_FBgcCbAvig?list=PL_pVmAaAnxIQGzQS2oI3OWEPT-dpmwTfA&t=4473) I would assume that for each observation it makes predictions using the trees that didn't use that observation and average them.

Comment: @ayhan: but that's exactly the definition of 'Out-Of-Bag'. After looking at the other question, I edited the title to [Computing Out of Bag error in Random Forest: is it the average only over trees that didn't use each sample?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68740/computing-out-of-bag-error-in-random-forest)

Comment: *"2. Or does scikit-learn perform some lookups first"* is needlessly vague. The doc says the OOB average (wrt each sample) is computed only over trees that didn't use that sample. That's it.